# WordPress - JS and CSS files being 301 redirected?

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, version, http-status-code-301

I’m having an issue with 301 redirects as they relate to .js and .css file version numbers. For instance, `/wp-includes/js/my-file.min.js?ver=4.9.1` redirects to `/wp-includes/js/my-file.min.js`. We are being asked to prevent the redirect from happening at all, but I’ve had no luck so far.

Does anyone have any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 1):

It's now **'redirects'**. It's just removing query strings from your `js/css` files. It may be done with some plugin, or function, which may inserted into your theme `functions.php` file, or somwhere else.

First of all, check all plugins, which may do it, such as [Remove Query Strings From Static Resources](https://wordpress.org/plugins/remove-query-strings-from-static-resources/), or some other plugin like this one.

If you don't have such plugins, try to check `functions.php` file of your active theme and find something like:

`add_filter( 'script_loader_src', '/*here will be some function name*/', 15, 1 );`
`add_filter( 'style_loader_src', '/*here will be some function name*/', 15, 1 );`

and delete/comment them.

Its also can be done with some js script, or with `.htaccess` file.